# How can I get MP3 flux with Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <MediaElement Height="120"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="-12,148,0,0"
                  Name="mediaPlayer"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="474"
                  AutoPlay="True"
    />
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
Uri Path = new Uri("http://streaming.acc.net:8000/kalilo");
mediaPlayer.Source = Path;
```

Comment: i mean that i want load a streaming audio file :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a unsupported type of stream. And since your link isn't valid, that's all the info we can provide.

Remember that you can't play music in the emulator, and on the device you need to use [WPConnect.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/katriend/archive/2010/10/26/quick-tip-using-the-wp-connect-utility-instead-of-zune-client-windows-phone-7.aspx) to connect instead of Zune, to make it actually play.

Comment: are u saying this because it doesn't end with .mp3!?

Comment: Well, you also need the extension in the path. Try add ?ext=.mp3 to the path.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a streaming service, `MediaElement` is a basic, but often unreliable source because of possible interruptions (e.g. switching from WiFi to a cell data connection). It works in most situations, but it has restrictions on media content that is passed through it.

Assuming that the URI you are showing belongs to a Shoutcast stream, it is not supported by default and you need to implement a connector through `MediaStreamSource`, even if you receive MP3 bytes.

[Here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/01/mediastreamsource-sample-with-source-code.aspx) is a great `MediaStreamSource` example from Tim Heuer.

Also worth checking out - [ManagedMediaHelpers](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers).